# Codeception setCookie issue

Tags: php, api, code-coverage, codeception

I need to run a CodeCoverage session on my Lumen-based project, but I get some weird error.

If I launch

```
codecept run api
```

everything works fine, but if I launch

```
codecept run api --coverage
```

the server crash and the tests fail.

Searching on google, let me to isolate the problem: I've found that if I comment

```
$this->module->setCookie(self::COVERAGE_COOKIE, json_encode($cookie));
```

On LocalServer.php:152 the tests are done successfully, so I figure that the problem is on the setCookie method.

This is my **api.suite.yml**

```
class_name: ApiTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - \Helper\Api
        - Lumen
        - Asserts
        - REST:
            depends: PhpBrowser
            url: http://localhost:8000/worklist/
```

Somebody have a solution to this bad problem?
Thanks for response

---

**EDIT**
I'm trying to investigate the problem, and I've discovered that my problems are caused by two line on the file LocalServer.php

```
$this->module->amOnPage('/');
$this->module->setCookie(self::COVERAGE_COOKIE, json_encode($cookie));
```

If I comment the first line, the server still crash but *codecept* run some codecoverage (not the full coverage analysis).
Instead, if I comment the second line everything work fine but no codecoverage analysis is done.

Comment: Do you have some error messages?

Comment: Unfortunately not, the only error that I have is

*** Error in `/home/sum/Scrivania/portable/lampstack-5.6.10-0/php/bin/php.bin': double free or corruption (!prev): 0x0000000002ffa670 ***

But if I comment the line of LocalServer, I have no problem, except that the coverage doesn't analyze the file in the whitelist